# Spring secure both web app and rest app

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I read a lot of manual of how to configure spring security, but still stuck with configuration.
So i want to configure rest calls and other http calls. As i understand i can create urls like /server/**  - for web application and /rest/** - for rest application. For any call of web application urls i want to create a login page (when user not authenticated), but for rest app, i want to fire Unauthorised code.

I do it with spring annotations by extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/server/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
}
```

for server it works fine, but if i try to add /rest here when i try to call /rest/[something] (in browser), it always forwards me to /login page.
I don't understand why and it is break my mind.
Thanks for any helpful responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
.antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/server/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
```

means / access need ROLE_ACCESS and for authentication, direct to formLogin

You need multiple authentication conf.

see http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

And in one of them you need something like this

```
http
        .antMatcher("/rest/**")
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AccessDenyEntryPoint()).and()                
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spring/**").denyAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more `.antMatchers("/rest/*").permitAll()` if you don't want to validate your rest urls.